# Найти среднее арифметическое четных и среднее геометрическое нечетных чисел

Tags: python, python-3.x

Накидал что-то вот такое, но не могу допетрить как дальше сделать. Подскажите пожалуйста.
'''
При помощи случайных чисел сформировать список,
 содержащий 15 натуральных чисел.
  Найти среднее арифметическое четных и среднее геометрическое нечетных чисел.
   На экран вывести список и найденные значения.
'''

```
spisok = [12, 32, 15, 27, 65, 22, 91, 63, 11, 40, 24, 47, 3, 18, 85]
kol_vo_spiska = len(spisok)
for i in range(kol_vo_spiska):
    sp = (spisok[i])
    if sp % 2 == 0:
        print(sp)
print(spisok)
```

Comment: У Вас проблема со средними?

Comment: У меня проблема с дальнейшим действием. Получаю чётные со списка, а как их и куда сложить? Чтобы потом ещё и разделить

Comment: Складывайте в сумму, делите на количество. В школе как среднее считали?

Comment: Школа... дело давно минувших дней... В этом и проблема, что уже ничего не помнится.

Comment: Тяжело вам придется...

Comment: Заново всё вспоминать, это точно(

Answer (score 2):

```
from functools import reduce
arr = [12, 32, 15, 27, 65, 22, 91, 63, 11, 40, 24, 47, 3, 18, 85]

even = [i for i in arr if i % 2 == 0] # Записали только четные
print(sum(even) / len(even))          # Поделили их сумму на кол-во

odd = [i for i in arr if i % 2 != 0]  # Записали только нечетные
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, odd) ** (1.0 / len(odd))) # Взяли корень n-степени из произведения
```

P.S. На счет производительности, боюсь представить что будет, если нечетные числа будут очень большие.

Answer (score 0):

Если речь идет о четных и нечетных индексах исходного списка:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [12, 32, 15, 27, 65, 22, 91, 63, 11, 40, 24, 47, 3, 18, 85]
print(np.mean(lst[::2]))
print(np.mean(lst[1::2]))
```

результат:

```
38.25
35.57142857142857
```

Если речь идет о четных и нечетных элементах исходного списка:

```
import numpy as np
lst = [12, 32, 15, 27, 65, 22, 91, 63, 11, 40, 24, 47, 3, 18, 85]
print(np.mean(np.extract(np.mod(lst,2)==0,lst)))
print(np.mean(np.extract(np.mod(lst,2)==1,lst)))
```

результат:

```
24.666666666666668
45.22222222222222
```

Comment: тут под четными и нечетными скорее всего другое понимается.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, тупанул маленько.